# Two Different date formats for record in datetimefield - we want to have one format

Tags: mysql, django, datetime

In our app, we use `Django 1.11` and `mySQL`.

In our production, we encounter a problem with the date format for a couple of columns.

For some record the returned format of DateTime field is in the form: `2018-03-03T14:48:43Z` and for others `2019-06-19T14:28:46+01:00`.

We would like to return only one format and I think that we prefer this: `2019-06-19T14:28:46+01:00`.

How to easily update the older record to use the new format?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you have timezone-unaware datetimes or whether they're UTC. You'll probably need to review commits and migrations to figure out whether you've actually lost data; if datetimes were being saved based on local times without timezones, there is no way to retrieve that data (you could potentially assume the timezone if you can track which user generated the data, if you keep timezone info for users, but that's definitely not foolproof). Unrelated, but you should also add upgrading to 2.x LTS to your roadmap.

Comment: I just wants to keep the format. Timezone does no metter

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question, then. TZ always matters if it's not constant between all of your datetime values.